# Django ElasticSearch returns only 10 rowsets

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am using ElasticSearch-DSL in my django application and the query returns only 10 rows.
When I use size. I get an error "multi_match" query does not support size.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import MultiMatch
# Create your views here.
from search.documents import CarDocument
from products.models import Products

def search(request):
   q = request.GET.get('q')
   if q:
       #cars = CarDocument.search().query("match", model_name=q)
      q = request.GET.get('q', None)
      query1 = MultiMatch(query=q,  fields=['product_make', 'bodystyle','model_name','variant','transmission','yom'])
      s = CarDocument.search().query(query1)
      cars = s.execute()
   else:
      cars = ''

   return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'cars': cars})
```

Comment: By default, it returns 10 data. If you want more than 10 data, like to get 50 data you can use `CarDocument.search()[:50]`

Answer (score 2):

With this, you shall get all records:

```
s = CarDocument.search().query(query1)
total = s.count()
s = s[0:total]
cars = s.execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, it returns 10 data. If you want more than 10 data, like to get 50 data you can use `CarDocument.search()[:50]`